# algorithmicx + babel + Hebrew incompatibility

Tags: algorithms, babel, incompatibility, hebrew, algorithmicx

When trying to create any document with `babel` and `algorithmicx`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

I get an error in `algorithmicx.sty`:

```
...
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithmicx\algorithmicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.636 \algnewlanguage{default}
                          %
```

This is slightly related to the [algorithmic + Hebrew babel conflict](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/algorithmic-babel-with-hebrew-conflict-numbering-missing) for which I got useful answers - but only in the sense of there seeming to be a long-standing package conflict which for some reason has not been resolved in a distribution.

I'm using MikTeX 2.9.

Comment: I also get this error with TeX Live 2011 (and also if I load the packages in the converse order).

Answer (score 5):

It is the same problem as mentioned in the question you linked to: hebrew redefines \@arabic and algorithmicx fails. Imho the faulty package is algorithmicx. It shouldn't use \arabic to get a number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\number#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\begin{document}
Hello, world.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this will break what `hebrew.ldf` does in order to change writing directions for numbers.

Comment: But what if I need the \@arabic as babel defines it, as egreg notes? I've tried going over the source of [the modified algorithmic.sty](http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~yoavg/tech-notes/heblatex/algorithmic.sty) linked to from the other question, to see if I could do something similar for algorithmicx, but I don't see where exactly in algorithmicx the problem is which causes the `\csname` to fail.

Comment: Specifically, I tried replacing the uses of `\arabic` with `\@@arabic`, which `rlbabel.def` makes a synonym of the 'original' `\arabic` - and that didn't work.

Comment: @egreg: Yes I know that it will break the definition of hebrew. I only wanted to show that the definition of `\@arabic` is the source of the problem. @Eyal: You must search for the places where algorithmicx use `\arabic{<counter>}`. They should probably all be replaced by `\the\value{<counter>}` or `\number\value{<counter}`. But better write to the author. He should change his code (and make the necessary tests).

Comment: @Ulrike: Have written the author, Szasz Janos. Seeing how there have been no updates for 6 years, I'm not optimistic. Also, I made this replacement (to `\number\value{<counter>}`), but then I get a `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error.

Comment: Well you should naturally replace `<counter>` by the real counter name. And you must do the replacement in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from `source2e`, when dealing with `\newcounter{foo}`:

> `\thefoo` and `\p@foo` *must* be deﬁned in such a way that `\edef\bar{\thefoo}` or `\edef\bar{\p@foo}` deﬁnes `\bar` so that it will evaluate to the counter value at the time of the `\edef`, even after `\c@foo` and any other counters have been changed. This will happen if you use the standard commands `\@arabic`, `\@Roman`, etc.

(the source says `\foocounter`, but it should be `\c@foo`).

Unfortunately, the **babel** module for Hebrew redefines `\@arabic` in a way that's not compatible with the specifications set forth in `source2e`: this is found in

```
\let\@@arabic\@arabic
\def\@arabic#1{\@number{\@@arabic#1}}
\def\@number{\protect\@@number}
\def\@@number#1{\ifmmode\else\beginL\fi#1\ifmmode\else\endL\fi}
```

*Any* package that relies on `\thefoo` expanding to the commands for representing the counter value will suffer from the same problems.

Comment: I presume you mean `\c@foo` instead of `\p@foo`?

Comment: @wh1t3 No, that's correct. With `\newcounter{foo}` also `\p@foo` is defined; usually it does nothing (`\def\p@foo{}`), but it's used in `\refstepcounter`: with `\refstepcounter{foo}`, `\@currentlabel` is defined to be the expansion of `\p@foo\thefoo`.

Comment: Interesting, I see that `\@definecounter` lets `\p@foo` to `\empty`. What I don't understand however, is how `\newcounter` then defines `\p@foo` in such a way that `\edef\bar{\p@foo}` defines `\bar` so that it will evaluate to the counter value at the time of the `\edef`.

Comment: @wh1t3 That's only an example; one probably would use `\edef\bar{\p@foo\thefoo}`, but one is free to do whatever they want with `\p@foo`.

Comment: The quote sets specifications for `\thefoo` and `\p@foo`, not for commands defined with this commands. Also more importantly it doesn't force `\@arabic`, `\@Roman` or any `\thefoo` to expand so that they can be used in contexts where a number is required - and that is how the package is using `\arabic`. They should only evaluate the counter, not give the value of the counter.

Comment: "This will happen if you use `\@arabic`…" seems quite clear to me. And `\arabic` is just a wrapper around `\@arabic`. For the same reason `\@Roman` is defined with a slow routine rather than with `\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}`.