# Babel + Hebrew + lipsum incompatibility

Tags: babel, incompatibility, hebrew

With:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You get:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.6 \end
        {document}
?
```

[The suggestions here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32220/5640) do not work around the problem.

Comment: One remark: I would define the language definitions as class options. They are forwarded to the packages, so each package (not only babel) will get the language. Or in other words: languages are document specific, not babel specific. This comment doesn't change anything for your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hebrew `babel` redefines all the counter representation mechanism and `lipsum` relies on `\roman` for its inner workings.

You can change a macro in `lipsum`:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\lips@dolipsum{%
  \ifnum\value{lips@count}<\lips@max\relax
    \addtocounter{lips@count}{1}%
    \csname lipsum@\romannumeral\c@lips@count\endcsname
    \lips@dolipsum
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

so that it uses the primitive way of converting numbers to roman numerals.

Or you can use the similar `kantlipsum` package that doesn't suffer from the problem to begin with. (Disclaimer: I'm the author of `kantlipsum`.)

Comment: ..or [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/blindtext) (Disclaimer: I'm the author of blindtext ;) )

Comment: Note to future readers: Changes to `lipsum` over the years have invalidated this workaround - but with newer TeX distribution, the original issue may be gone as well.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, now `lipsum` uses `expl3` and no longer relies on `\roman`.