# nomenclature does not print, possibly because of hebrew babel distrupting makeindex

Tags: indexing, babel, hebrew, nomencl

I have been trying to print an automated nomenclature using `nomencl` in a multilingual document. 
It does not work, here is a MWE.

Removing everything hebrew from it (from the `babel` definition and everything from `\begin{otherlanguage}...`) generates a nomenclature. This has led me to believe that the reason the nomenclature does not print is the `babel` messing up with `makeindex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
blah blah blah 
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
נסיון
\end{otherlanguage}
\nomenclature{ab}{a aand b}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

`makeindex` on CTAN has a hebrew support readme file, but none of the mirrors for the download provided in that file work.

In addition, I am currently working with Overleaf, and would prefer not resorting to installing extra support, as that would require installing extra editors on several computers...

My question is this: Is the problem really with `makeindex` ? And whether it is or isn't, how do I solve the problem ?

UPDATE:

`glossaries` package has a no makeindex option (option 1 in the CTAN documentation). This enables for the automatic generation of acronym and symbols list. This solves my problem only partly, as most of my work is written using `/nomenclature` definitions in the body of the text, reverting to `glossaries` would require moving all these definitions to the preamble. Still waiting for a better solution.

UPDATE 2.0:

Here is the log of the makeindex run:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist.......
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 70):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 71):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_suffix.
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 72):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_flag.
...done (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file filename.nlo...
!! Input index error (file = filename.nlo, line = 1):
   -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.
done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in filename.nls.
Transcript written in filename.ilg.
```

the content of filename.nlo

```
\nomenclatureentry{aab@[{ab}]\begingroup a aand b\nomeqref {\@@number {\@@number {0}}}|nompageref}{\@@number {1}}
```

Comment: what are your `makeindex` settings?

Comment: what messages does `makeindex` report? (`makeindex` should have written information to a transcript file.)

Comment: @naphaneal I'm using `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`. @Nicola Talbot I edited the question to add the makeindex log. There does seem to be a problem there

Comment: What does `filename.nlo` contain? Looks like `makeindex` is complaining about the page number. As far as I know, `makeindex` only recognises arabic numerals (0, 1, ...) latin letters (a, b, ..., A, B, ...) and roman numerals (i, ii, ..., I, II, ...) in the location (optionally with a separator).

Comment: edited again to add nlo content

Comment: I suspect that `babel` changed the numbering, there was a slight problem with `babel` and `algorithmic`, but the solution to that did not solve the `nomencl` problem. Had I had more time I would have put a bounty on this. But I don't so I switched to `glossaries`.

Comment: @EladDen: Something unrelated, but are you loading the languages in the correct order? I think at the moment Hebrew is the main language.

Comment: you are correct, this way it turns the blah into hlab. but changing it to the right way, still does not help with makeindex...

Comment: `makeindex` doesn't like the `\@@number` bit in the location. (I suspect it probably also doesn't like the internal commands in the first argument of `\nomenclatureentry` since `@` is one of `makeindex`'s special characters.) I'm guessing the problem is in the definition of `\thepage`, which doesn't expand to a form that's compatible with `makeindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, following @Nicola Talbots remark, and following [This problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187872/90297) with Babel and Algorithm2e I came up with the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\def\@number#1{\number#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
blah blah blah

\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}
נסיון
\end{otherlanguage}
\nomenclature{ab}{a aand b}
\nomenclature{ba}{b aand a}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The definition of `\@number` removes the \@@number from the .nlo file. Now when running pdflatex->makeindex->pdflatex the nomenclature works.

This makes my MWE run perfectly, however I am pretty sure the `@number` macro has some sort of significance, I cannot check what other problems this patch gives rise to.