# Copied algorithm2e code renderes different

Tags: lyx, algorithm2e

I'm writing a summary of my algorithms course and in order to insert new algorithms I use algorithm2e package. I am still learning the package features, so I tried to copy the code from [latex wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithm2e_package).

Unfortunately, after rendering my file, the result is different.

According to wikibook, the result should be [image: wikibook example],

but my result is

[image: my result]

I prefer that the caption will be above code rather than below (as shown in my result). I don't understand why in my result the while loop is not in next level to initialization, but at the same line.

My code (same to the one in wikibook, except that I use linesnumbered):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwData{this text}  
    \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }  
    initialization\;  
    \While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
        \eIf{understand}{go to next section\;    
            current section becomes this one\;}
        {go back to the beginning of current section\;}  
    }  
    \caption{How to write algorithms}   
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

What should I do? thanks!

Comment: Can you turn your snippet in to a complete example, so that it can be copied and compiled directly? (I.e. it should start with `\documentclass`, contain the necessary packages and definitions but no more, and end with `\end{document}`.) There are several packages for writing pseudocode, so for those not very familiar with all of them it's very helpful to know which are used. (Edit: Yes, I see that you mention `algorithm2e`, but compilable examples are always preferable I think.)

Comment: (Continued.) I just tested your code with `algorithm2e` and it produces an output like the one from the Wikibook. In other words you have some other algorithm-package that is changing things.

Comment: That code does not produce the output in your second image. The caption is below and there are no lines: http://i.imgur.com/8ujfxLQ.png

Comment: @TorbjørnT., I think you are correct. I'm using lyx and there is a collision between the standard algorithm package of lyx and algorithm2e. I defined lyx to use algorithm2e, but then I can't use linesnumbered. How can I get the lines numbered and the caption above?

Comment: I don't really have an answer at the moment, will try to have a look later today if I have time (unless someone else answers).

Comment: did you add algorithm2e in Document->settings->modules ? if so I don't know how to add linesnumbered. What I usually do is add in the preamble (Document->settings->LaTeX preamble) `\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: I've found an answer for my problem [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24421/algorithmic-babel-with-hebrew-conflict-numbering-missing), so I'm using algorithmic instead of algorithm2e and it works flawlessly. Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: @Galc127 -- although you pointed to a question where you found an answer to your problem, that question is sufficiently different that it might be difficult for someone else looking there to figure out what it is.  you could help future visitors by adding a self-answer here, so that it's entirely clear what youdid.